# background color from position

Tags: css, background-color

I have to start background-color from certain position and not to apply for whole element.

**html**

```
<p class="tax-free-keksis">text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here  text heretext here text here</p>
```

**css**

```
p.tax-free-keksis {
background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/poga_keksis.png);
background-position: left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #c2e8fb;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-align: left;
}
```

link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MVST6/

I need background-color: #c2e8fb to start about 50px from left (so that checkmark image backround is white and not blue).

I think that I cannot position background-color in some "normal" way. Here I need some fix I am not aware of, as I am not CSS developer and I am new to designing webpage.

Comment: I think the CSS pseudo-selectors `:before` and `:after` will help to achieve this, check em out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with a background color, but possible with [a gradient background image](http://jsfiddle.net/MVST6/3/):

```
background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50px, #c2e8fb 50px),
    url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/poga_keksis.png);
```

And if you need to support oldie browsers, you have two use two elements: one with a background color and other one with a background image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

p.tax-free-keksis {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c2e8fb;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.tax-free-keksis:before {
    content: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/poga_keksis.png);
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="tax-free-keksis">text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text heretext here text here
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way. Maybe try something like this:

HTML

```
<p class="tax-free-keksis">
    <img src="http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/poga_keksis.png">
        text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text heretext here text hered
    </p>
```

CSS

```
p.tax-free-keksis {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #c2e8fb;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
p.tax-free-keksis img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -50px;
    top: -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: -120px; 
width: 50%; 
height: 100%; 
border-right:1px solid #d0d0d0; 
background-color: red; (if you want you can put image here)
z-index: -10;
```

this code is for image. Then, You should give a style to text and give padding to it.

Comment: I do not understand your answer.